# why will this sound loop not stop?

Tags: objective-c, audio, avfoundation, uialertview, avaudioplayer

I made a sound loop in my app that I want to stop when the user presses the 'ok' button on a `UIAlertView` that comes up.

I have 2 problems though:

---

### First

When I have breakpoints on and I set a breakpoint for all exceptions, an exception appears on `[audioPlayer play]` but no error is shown on the log and the app does not crash after 'F8-ing' through the exception except there is no sound.

---

### Second

The other problem I'm having is that the audio file wont stop after the user taps the 'ok' button, and breakpointing through shows that it does read the `[audioPlayer stop]` call.  I have no idea what is causing these errors and nothing I do seems to help.

---

### Code

```
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;


-(void)done {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timer Done" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
    [alert show];

    [self playAlert];
}

-(void)playAlert {
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Alarm" ofType:@"caf"];
    NSURL *soundFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundFilePath];
    audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:soundFileURL error:nil];
    audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = -1; //infinite

    [audioPlayer play];
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
    if (buttonIndex == 1) {
        if ([audioPlayer isPlaying]) {
            [audioPlayer stop];
        }
    }
}
```

Please let me know what I can do to fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One obvious problem is that you passed nil as the UIView delegate so you will never get called back.

i.e.

```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timer Done" message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
```

should be:

```
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Timer Done" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"Ok", nil];
```

Another problem is that the buttonIndex starts at zero.  So on the callback you should check for zero not one.

Comment: Thanks! For some reason, I did not see those problems in my code... must have typed it too fast!